# CSS3 -moz-transform-origin not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create vertical angled effect using css3 and transform:skewY(). Problem is that when I use -moz-transform-origin to start from the bottom left corner of the screen firefox does not work as the rest of implementations do. Effect works as expected in chrome, safari and edge. Problem can be seen [here](http://dev.iseguro.com/negociar).

Code I'm using is as follows.

```css
.skew-heading {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #0A996F;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

    .skew-heading:after {
        content: '';
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 0px;
        background: white;
        z-index: -1;
    }

.skew-heading-2:after {
    -webkit-transform: skewY(-9deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(-9deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(-9deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(-9deg);
    transform: skewY(-9deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
}
```

Comment: Don't use vendor prefix properties. They are *experimental* features. Firefox has supported the unprefixed `transform-origin` for half a **decade**!

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] in the question itself. The HTML this is supposed to apply to is missing.

Comment: Small note, you use `0 0` for webkit and `top` for the rest...?

Comment: It's because `.align-outer` has `display: table` and that's messing up the positioning of the pseudo element. Your transform and transform-origin are fine. Remove that `display: table` property and firefox looks like the other browsers.

Comment: Thanks. It was the display:table entry. Answer the questions so I can mark it as a solution.